# Global style is overridden by user-agent stylesheet

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and I am having an issue with styling. I want to use scoped style for most of my components but I still have some common CSS rules I want to be shared, like font-family.

To do this I created a CSS file in the `public` folder and I linked it in the `index.html`. The style is correctly inherited in my components however they are overridden by the user-agent stylesheet.

The same happens when I use a scoped style for my root component and set the font-family to be inherited by child components.

Here is for instance the style block of my root component:

```
<style scoped>
#app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: Nunito;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #232526, #414345);
}
</style>
```

And here is a capture of how Chrome interprets the CSS. At the top is my child component style (`.spotify-button`) and at the bottom is my root component style (`#app`).

[image]

How am I supposed to share style accross my components?

Comment: Do you have any examples of the rules you're setting and how they're being overridden?

Comment: So is it just the `font-family` you're worried about?

Comment: For now yes but it's because I'm only starting. There will surely be other properties I will want to be shared.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it was related to form elements not inheriting style like other elements... Thanks!

Comment: No worries. You should find other elements inherit correctly